# How do I use `ember-emojione` with `emojione-png-sprites`?

Tags: ember.js, ember-emojione

I'm using [ember-emojione](https://github.com/Deveo/ember-emojione) to display and insert emoji.

Out of four rendering options that EmojiOne offers:

- PNG sprites
- PNG individual images
- SVG sprites
- SVG individual images

...only PNG sprites suit me. Individual images take too much time to load and emoji display sequentially. SVG sprites are awesome, but rerendering the preview area causes SVG sprite emoji to flicker. Only PNG sprite emoji never flicker and display simultaneously.

Unfortunately, EmojiOne offers spritesheets only in three sizes: 64, 128 and 512 px. We need to display emoji in 20 px size.

Resizing emoji displayed via PNG sprites is problematic.

`ember-emojione` readme suggests this hack to resize PNG sprite emoji:

```
.emojione {
  transform: scale(0.3125);
  margin: -22px;
}
```

It works, but it has some disadvantages:

- In certain cases, emoji appear blurred.
- Text selection blows up:

  [image]

The solution is to use emoji spritesheets tailored to desired size. The [Deveo/emojione-png-sprites](https://github.com/Deveo/emojione-png-sprites) repo offers such spritesheets.

But when I include those spritesheets instead of default ones, `ember-emojione` emoji picker component displays incorrectly.

**Question**: how do I use `ember-emojione` with `emojione-png-sprites` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emojione-png-sprites` relies on Sass mixins, so you'll need `ember-cli-sass`. If you don't want to install `ember-cli-sass`, you can alternatively precompile mixin invocations manually and insert resulting CSS into your app.

1. Decide which spritesheets to include from `emojione-png-sprites`.

   We're gonna use **20px** emoji. For retina, we'll also need double and triple size spritesheets. As 40px and 60px aren't available, we're gonna use next available ones: **48px** and **64px**.
2. Include spritesheets and the Sass file into your repo. Run these commands in your Ember app root:

   ```
   bower i -S emojione-png-sprite-20=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deveo/emojione-png-sprites/v0.3.0/dist/sprite-20.png
   bower i -S emojione-png-sprite-48=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deveo/emojione-png-sprites/v0.3.0/dist/sprite-48.png
   bower i -S emojione-png-sprite-64=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deveo/emojione-png-sprites/v0.3.0/dist/sprite-64.png
   bower i -S emojione-png-sprite-style=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deveo/emojione-png-sprites/v0.3.01/dist/style.scss
   ```

   It's very important that you use a specific release version of the files, so that your dependencies are locked. Otherwise, if the repo has a breaking change, an innocent `bower install` will break your project.
3. Tell `ember-emojione` not to include default EmojiOne CSS and spritesheets. In your app's `ember-cli-build.js`:

   ```
   module.exports = function (defaults) {
       var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {    
           "ember-emojione": {
               shouldImportCss:        false,
               shouldIncludePngSprite: false,
               shouldIncludeSvgSprite: false,
               shouldIncludePngImages: false,
               shouldIncludeSvgImages: false
           }
       });
   // ...
   ```
4. Import PNG sprites into your app.

   Install `broccoli-funnel`:

   ```
   npm install -D broccoli-funnel
   ```

   In your app's `ember-cli-build.js`:

   ```
   var Funnel = require("broccoli-funnel");

   module.exports = function (defaults) {
       var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
               // ...
           }
       });

       const funnels = [

           // PNG sprites
           new Funnel(app.bowerDirectory + "/emojione-png-sprite-20", {
               include: ['index.png'],
               getDestinationPath () {
                   return "assets/emojione-png-sprites/sprite-20.png";
               }
           }),
           new Funnel(app.bowerDirectory + "/emojione-png-sprite-48", {
               include: ['index.png'],
               getDestinationPath () {
                   return "assets/emojione-png-sprites/sprite-48.png";
               }
           }),
           new Funnel(app.bowerDirectory + "/emojione-png-sprite-64", {
               include: ['index.png'],
               getDestinationPath () {
                   return "assets/emojione-png-sprites/sprite-64.png";
               }
           }),
       ];

       if (app.env === "development" || app.env === "test") {
           app.import(app.bowerDirectory + "/timekeeper/lib/timekeeper.js");
       }

       return app.toTree(funnels);
   };
   ```
5. In your app's Sass, include the mixin and invoke it:

   ```
   @import "bower_components/emojione-png-sprite-style/index.scss";

   @include sprity-emojione(20, "/assets/emojione-png-sprites", (2: 48, 3: 64));
   ```
6. This will break the looks of `ember-emojione` components. The addon contains a mixin that restores the looks:

   ```
   @import 'node_modules/ember-emojione/app/styles/ember-emojione';

   @include ember-emojione-cancel-scale;
   ```